# How can ban a user in google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

Well is that possible to ban or block a user to send any data to leaderboards or etc. Because someuser are looking not a real person I want block those user but how?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67123/how-can-i-remove-scores-or-ban-users-from-google-play-leaderboards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about google play leaderboards, not a specific programming problem.